# Border between rows in calling sql database

Tags: php, mysql, row, border

I'm not able to do borders between rows and I'm not sure why
Please help me.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mysql", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cloud team` WHERE `Vendor` = 'Juniper' ");
echo "<table align='center' bgcolor='#F9F0F0' border='#190707' cellspacing='#190707'>
<tr>
      <th><font color='red'>Juniper</font></th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center' style='vertical-align:text-top' width='500px'>";

    echo "<a ='send.php'>"  . " " . $row['Vendor']  . " " . $row['MGMT IP']  . " " . $row['Version']  . " " . $row['GUI User']  . " " . $row['GUI Pass']  . " " . $row['Notes'] . "</a></td>";


    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the output of this code looks like this :

[image]

And I want borders between rows ..
Any help?

Comment: Perhaps an individual <td> for each individual element of $row, rather than concatenating them all into a single <td>

Comment: Please stop using PHP's archaic, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: I see a border between the header row and the row with `Juniper 1.1.1.1`. What border are you missing?

Comment: You did it! There are borders on the table

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a border between the rows in the result, not rows in the html table, then just change your line from this

`echo "<a ='send.php'>"  . " " . $row['Vendor']  . " " . $row['MGMT IP']  . " " . $row['Version']  . " " . $row['GUI User']  . " " . $row['GUI Pass']  . " " . $row['Notes'] . "</a></td>";`

to this

`echo "<a ='send.php'>"  . " </td.<td> " . $row['Vendor']  . " </td.<td> " . $row['MGMT IP']  . " </td.<td> " . $row['Version']  . " </td.<td> " . $row['GUI User']  . "</td.<td> " . $row['GUI Pass']  . "</td.<td> " . $row['Notes'] . "</a></td>";`

And you really should use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql for the connection, as Strawberry kindly pointed out.

Comment: Hi bsguy

Thanks .. but this still not giving me borders between rows ..

Comment: Thanks bsguy , Problem has been resolved by this code:


echo "<thead><th>Vendor</th><th>MGMT IP</th><th>Version</th><th>GUI User</th><th>GUI Pass</th></thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";


echo "<a ='send.php'>" . "<td> " . $row['Vendor']  . " <td> " . $row['MGMT IP']  . " <td> " . $row['Version']  . " <td> " . $row['GUI User']  . "<td> " . $row['GUI Pass']  . "<td> " . $row['Notes']. "</a></td>";